# Google Prediction API - storageDataLocation?

Tags: google-prediction

Any experience on how to specify the Google prediction buckets. I went ahead and created a bucket in Storage --> Cloud Storage --> Browser by clicking button Create bucket. I named the bucket a unique name say "UNIQUE001". I uploaded data based on their specifications, a CSV file, quoted if strings. I want to train the model and so want to run Prediction API v1.6 > prediction.trainedmodels.insert. Here is my post request

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.6/projects/XXXXXXXXX/trainedmodels?fields=created%2Cid%2Ckind%2CmodelInfo%2CmodelType%2CselfLink%2CstorageDataLocation%2CstoragePMMLLocation%2CstoragePMMLModelLocation%2CtrainingComplete%2CtrainingStatus

    {
     "id": "CodePrediction",
     "storageDataLocation": "dataset.csv",
     "modelType": "CLASSIFICATION"
    }
```

I get a response as error "Training data not found"
400 OK

Show headers -

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Training data file not found."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Training data file not found."
 }
}
```

Not sure, how to specify storageDataLocation, I guess. I tried
1) gs://UNIQUE001
2) ProjectNumber/UNIQUE001

Here is the error when I give ProjectNumber/bucketName,

```
Request
POST https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.6/projects/xxxx/trainedmodels?fields=created%2Cid%2Ckind%2CmodelInfo%2CmodelType%2CselfLink%2CstorageDataLocation%2CstoragePMMLLocation%2CstoragePMMLModelLocation%2CtrainingComplete%2CtrainingStatus

{
 "id": "CodePrediction",
 "storageDataLocation": "xxxxxxx/UNIQUE001",
 "modelType": "CLASSIFICATION"
}
```

Error

400 OK

Show headers -

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Training data file is empty.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "id"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Training data file is empty."
 }
}
```

The data set is not empty. It has million lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storageDataLocation value is bucketname/filename